# Xcode: reverting back to default color in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, colors, components

I am trying to find a way to revert back to the system default color programmatically for iOS components using code. The only other way would be to use 2 controls - 1 set to either color and switch them.

[image: Current Color to Default Color]

Any info is appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: What control? What specifically do you wish to reset to the default? Have you looked at the documentation for that control?

Comment: TextViews. You can change controls simply by stating something like: control.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];  for purposes of highlighting the control - then changing it back to its default color once the user is finished using it.  There is no known command that I came across that restores the default color.

Comment: If you know how to set the text view's background color, what is your question?

Comment: Going back to the DEFAULT color... is the issue.

Comment: Did you try setting the background color to `nil`?

Comment: Neither Nil nor Clear works as the default color has a transparent background.

Answer (score 0):

I tried below code in order to change the background of a button to its default color and it worked for me

```
submitBtn.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
```